# Centralizar flexbox

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox, css

Olá, sou novato em **CSS3/HTML5/JAVASCRIPT**, estou cursando diversos relativos a estas linguagens, porém fiquei em duvida relativa a centralização de um flex;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O do professor centralizava e aparentemente fiz a mesma coisa, porém sem sucesso. Fiquei horas relendo o codigo e achei que poderia estar desatualizado, então fui até **https://developer.mozilla.org/** analisar a documentação e estava do mesmo jeito cujo professor fez. O que pode estar acontecendo? Pode ser um problema no meu navegador?

## Vou deixar o script abaixo

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### HTML5

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Flexbox</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="child" ></div>
        <div class="child" ></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### CSS3##

```
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
}
.child{
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px

}
```

Comment: Peço desculpas pelo erro no codigo CSS, mas inves de duas vezes   
   > justify-items: center;
       
Eu estava utilizando   
    justify-items: center;
    justify-content: center;    
        
Então o erro não foi exatamente esse.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -4):

No seu CSS, use align-items: center

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center; // aqui
}
.child {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Para quem está aprendendo FlexBox recomendo esse site: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/, é bem intuitivo e fácil de entender.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Eu entendi depois que eu não estava respeitando a sintaxe, embora eu estivesse usando align items. Foi bem tentativa e erro, mas muito obrigado pela dica.